# Android - Custom Icons in ListView

Tags: android, listview, icons

Is there any way to place a custom icon for each group item?  Like for phone I'd like to place a phone, for housing I'd like to place a house.  Here is my code, but it keeps throwing a Warning and locks up on me.

```
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
                //ExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(data);
                List<Map<String, Object>> groupData = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
               // List<List<Map<String, Object>>> childData = new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>();

                Iterator it = data.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) 
                {
                    //Get the key name and value for it
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    String keyName = (String) pair.getKey();
                    String value = pair.getValue().toString();

                    //Add the parents -- aka main categories
                    Map<String, Object> curGroupMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    groupData.add(curGroupMap);
                    Log.i("VAL", keyName);
                    if (keyName.equalsIgnoreCase("Phone"))
                        curGroupMap.put("ICON", findViewById(R.drawable.phone_icon));
                    else if (keyName.equalsIgnoreCase("Housing"))
                        curGroupMap.put("ICON", findViewById(R.drawable.house_icon));
                    else
                        curGroupMap.put("ICON", findViewById(R.drawable.house_icon));

                    curGroupMap.put("NAME", keyName);
                    curGroupMap.put("VALUE", value);


                }

                // Set up our adapter
                mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        mContext,
                        groupData,
                        R.layout.exp_list_parent,
                        new String[] { "ICON", "NAME", "VALUE" },
                        new int[] { R.id.photoAlbumImg, R.id.rowText1, R.id.rowText2  }
                        );

                myList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The error i'm getting:

```
    05-28 17:36:21.738: WARN/System.err(494): java.io.IOException: Is a directory
05-28 17:36:21.809: WARN/System.err(494):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.readImpl(Native Method)
05-28 17:36:21.838: WARN/System.err(494):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.read(OSFileSystem.java:158)
05-28 17:36:21.851: WARN/System.err(494):     at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:319)
05-28 17:36:21.879: WARN/System.err(494):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:183)
05-28 17:36:21.908: WARN/System.err(494):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:346)
05-28 17:36:21.918: WARN/System.err(494):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-28 17:36:21.937: WARN/System.err(494):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:459)
05-28 17:36:21.948: WARN/System.err(494):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:271)
05-28 17:36:21.958: WARN/System.err(494):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:296)
05-28 17:36:21.978: WARN/System.err(494):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:801)
05-28 17:36:21.988: WARN/System.err(494):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:501)
05-28 17:36:21.998: WARN/System.err(494):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:289)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (value == "Phone")
```

You need to use `equals` to compare strings. Most probably your code to set the drawable is thus never executed, and then the simpleadapter tries to load your string as a file, and you get your weird error.

Comment: I fixed this but still am encountering the same error the code is as follows:
               if (keyName.equalsIgnoreCase("Phone"))
                curGroupMap.put("ICON", (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.phone_icon));
               else if (keyName.equalsIgnoreCase("Housing"))
                curGroupMap.put("ICON", (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.house_icon));
               else
                curGroupMap.put("ICON", (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.house_icon));

Comment: @Ryan: the second part of your comment directly contradicts the first part.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited my code above to reflect what it currently looks like.  Thanks for taking time to help me.  It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ahhhh nvm, figured it out.  I have to leave off the findViewById().  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you shouldn't compare string values with the == operator, instead use the .equals function.  == asks if the two values point to the same object.  .equals asks if the two objects are functionally equivalent, i.e. do they have the same string value.

Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this:

```
else if (value == "Housing")
curGroupMap.put("NAME", keyName);
curGroupMap.put("VALUE", value);
```

It has the effect if this:

```
else if (value == "Housing") {
    curGroupMap.put("NAME", keyName);
}
curGroupMap.put("VALUE", value);
```

I doubt that is what you intended?  It is considered good style to always use the {}, even if there is only one line in the if statement so you don't run into problems like this.

As to the error message, is that realy what is says?  "Is a directory"?  It seems like it is having a hard time reading your image... Is it somehow corrupt, or misconfigured in your drawable file?